# how to get field value from database and pass to function?

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli

I make two function i want to get location_4 values from first function as $id and pass its values array to the second function how i do this?here is my code:

```
function getbussinessdetail($profit_id)
{
    $select="select a.account_id,a.title,a.budget,a.location_4,a.renewal_date,l.name from listing a,listinglevel l where l.value=a.level and profit_instructor_id='".$profit_id."' group by a.account_id";
    $result = $GLOBALS ['mysqli']->query ($select) or die ($GLOBALS ['mysqli']->error . __LINE__);
    while($rs=$result->fetch_assoc ())
    {
            $res[]=$rs;
    }       
    return $res;
}   
function getCityName($id)
{
    if($id>0)
    {
        $select="select name from Location_4 where id=$id";
        $result = $GLOBALS ['mysqli1']->query ($select) or die ($GLOBALS ['mysqli1']->error . __LINE__);
        $rs=$result->fetch_assoc ();

        return $rs['name']; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $profit_id = 4;
 $res = array();
 $res = getbussinessdetail($profit_id);

 if(count($res) > 0)
 {
   $cityNames = array();
   foreach($res as $id)
   {
    $cityNames[] = getCityNames($id['location_4']);
   }

 }

 var_dump($cityNames);
```

Or, just update the first query and get rid of the second function:

```
 $select="select a.account_id,a.title,a.budget,a.location_4,a.renewal_date,
          l.name from listing a,listinglevel l where l.value=a.level 
          and profit_instructor_id='".$profit_id."' group by a.account_id";
```

With this one:

```
 $select= "select a.account_id,a.title,a.budget,
      (select name from Location_4 where id=a.location_4) as cityName,
       a.renewal_date, l.name 
      from listing a,listinglevel l 
      where l.value=a.level 
      and profit_instructor_id='".$profit_id."' group by a.account_id";
```

Comment: this is not my question my question is to get arrays of location_4 field and pass as $id to the function getCityName($id)

Comment: Did you try the code at least...i think this is a very good aproach??

Comment: location_4 table in another database